# Auto include new files created outside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

**Problem:**

Images that I create outside of Visual Studio doesnt automaticlly get included into my project if I save the image somewhere in the projects folder structure.

**Question:**

Is there a way to automatically include new files thats been added to any folder in the project?

Im also using Source Control (Team foundation server), it would be nice if new files gets added to it aswell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no automatic inclusion into the project available based on folder path. 
In VS2012 there is a detected changes feature in Team Explorer where you will see any files added/deleted outside of VS in the Detected link under Excluded Changes.

For the source control addition problem you should consider using the TFS power tools which have a windows explorer extension. Using this you can directly add your new files to tfs with a right click option.

Answer (score 2):

Use wildcards in your project file. For example:

```
<Content Include="images\*" />
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the need to reload the project to include changes

Comment: That's true, but if you're working with something other than Visual Studio it's working fine, for example: http://royduineveld.nl/blog/en/tips-trucs/546/tfs-en-builden-vanuit-sublime-text-2/