# Visual Studio - Automatically include new files in project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a web app that generates some configuration files that I need to include into my VS-project. I know this can be done manually and also that there is a wildcard-solution ([Auto include new files created outside Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14891345/auto-include-new-files-created-outside-visual-studio)) but I'm not really pleased with this.

I need the files to be included without having to reload the project, and also VS sometimes changes the wildcard configuration and reference the individual files.

I'm thinking that there might be some plugin etc that could to this? Something with a file system watcher that includes the files?

Or does anyone know how to prevent VS from changing the wildcard-config?

Edit: I think that the changed in the csproj are triggered when you ie add a new file to the project. Then VS removes the folder** and adds a direct reference to all the files included and to the new file.

Edit 2: Seems like this works until you remove a file from the solution explorer, that's when VS creates all these "hard" references to a file.

I came up with a solution that seems to work, that is importing an external project, in my YadaYada.Web.csproj:

```
<Import Project="..\CustomBuild.targets" />
```

And then in CustomBuild.targets

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">  
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyConfigurationFolder\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

This will included the files in my builds but not in the VS-ui which is probably fine for me.

Thanks!

Comment: As the [visual-studio] tag states "Please mention your exact VS version, edition, and update level in your question."

Comment: Sorry, it's Visual Studio 2017